# why this error is showing "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now." during add bundle product in cart in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, bundled-product

I will change price of simple product in cart through observer,it will change successfully.This product is also part of bundle product.When we add this product in cart it display error We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.below is my observer code.Please tell me how to solve it in magento 2.1?

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
 {
    /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getProduct()->getTypeId() != Type::TYPE_BUNDLE  ) {
        foreach ($item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $bundleitems) {
            /** @var $bundleitems\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
            //Skip the bundle product
            if ($bundleitems->getProduct()->getCategoryId() =='6') {
                continue;
            }
        }

        $customprice=$bundleitems->getProduct()->getData('twopiece');
            //$customprice=$customprice+300;
            $bundleitems->setCustomPrice($customprice);
            $bundleitems->setOriginalCustomPrice($customprice);   
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
    return $this;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide your observer code, It hard to find out the reason for the error.

You can try to implement product type checking and change your code in observer accordingly.

The code you have written in observer may work only for simple product's add to cart operation. The observer code may need to change for Bundle and other products types.

Thank you

Comment: I will update my question with observer code @Pritam Info 24

Answer (score 0):

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
 {
    $quote_item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $price = 100; //set your price here
    $quote_item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
    $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

This works for me. It will update product price for all types of products.

Comment: It will work. Suppose we change price of one simple product .After that we create a bundle product,That simple product is added in bundle option.When we add to cart of bundle product it show error which are discussed above.